# "Улыбнуться от воспоминания"

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Я улыбнулся от воспоминания.

Вроде и употребляется такое выражение, и даже у Достоевского такое встречается, но есть ощущение, что с этим выражением что-то не то. Можно ли так написать? Или может, правильней было бы написать *"улыбнулся воспоминанию"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**УЛЫБНУТЬСЯ**,  св. 1. к Улыбаться. У. радостно. У. зло. **У. от счастья**. У. другу. Счастье улыбнулось девушке. Студенту улыбнулась удача.

В Нацкорпусе много примеров с предлогом ОТ и Р.п. Обычно улыбаются от удовольствия, от радости, то есть от различных чувств или мыслей.

Есть пример: *улыбнулся от неожиданной догадки*.

Поэтому  **в контексте** так можно сказать: **улыбнулся от (этого) воспоминания.**  При этом данной фразе предшествует описание воспоминаний.

А форма Д.п. больше подходит для одушевленных предметов (улыбнулся кому).